# Sequelize - SQL Server - Order One to Many Associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sql-order-by, backend, one-to-many

I have a problem, I contextualize I have 3 tables 1 for the trips, 1 for the points of interest and 1 other which makes the connection between the trips and the points of interests.

When I GET the trips I get this :

[image: Postman request - 1]
[image: Postman request - 2]

My code is this one for the GET request :

```
include: [
  {
    model: CategoryTrips,
    as: "categories",
    attributes: ["id", "category"],
    through: {
      attributes: [],
    },
  },
  {
    model: PointOfInterest,
    as: "pointsOfInterest",
    attributes: [
      "id",
      "title",
      "description",
      "photo",
      "website",
      "practicalinfo",
      "address",
      "city",
      "zipcode",
      "latitude",
      "longitude",
    ],
    // include: [{
    //   model: PointTrip,
    //   as: "pointTrip",
    //   separate: true,
    //   order: [["rank", "ASC"]],
    // }],
  },
  {
    model: Client,
    as: "client",
    attributes: ["id", "storeName", "website"],
  },
  {
    model: Picture,
    as: "pictures",
    attributes: ["id", "path"],
  },
],
```

I would like to understand how it is possible to sort the points of interest in the trips query from the association table "rank" fields

Can you help me please